# Как изменить заголовок в админ панели Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Дано: Wordpress, Woocommerce, заголовок Товары.

Для удобства установили плагин интернет-магазина, но по факту ничего на сайте не продается. Поэтому надо переименовать Товары в конкретный предмет, чтобы у пользователя не было недопониманий. В меню с помощью плагина смогла, а вот на странице в админке нет.

Как это можно реализовать?

[image: Тот самый заголовок]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно изменить с помощью фильтра `woocommerce_register_post_type_product`. И не забудьте удалить тот плагин, которым вы переименовали меню. Это решение переменует Товары везде где только можно.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product', 'rename_product' );
function rename_product( $args ){
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __( 'Tours', 'your-domain' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'Tour', 'your-domain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Tours', 'Admin menu name', 'your-domain' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'Add Tour', 'your-domain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Tour', 'your-domain' ),
        'edit'               => __( 'Edit', 'your-domain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Tour', 'your-domain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Tour', 'your-domain' ),
        'view'               => __( 'View Tour', 'your-domain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Tour', 'your-domain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Tours', 'your-domain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Tours found', 'your-domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Tours found in trash', 'your-domain' ),
        'parent'             => __( 'Parent Tour', 'your-domain' )
    );

    $args['labels'] = $labels;
    $args['description'] = __( 'This is where you can add new tours to your store.', 'your-domain' );
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобралась!

Answer (score 0):

> надо переименовать Товары в конкретный предмет

Переименование любых родных переводов можно осуществить с помощь плагинов [say-what](https://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/) или [loco-translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/).
Со вторым нужно создать свой лангпак в отдельном каталоге и изменить его.

Дополнительно можно почитать у коллеги: [Как скорректировать перевод WordPress, темы или плагина под себя](https://wpcute.ru/blog/kak-skorrektirovat-perevod-wordpress-temyi-ili-plagina-pod-sebya/)

**Добавлено**: это правильный способ, рекомендуемый разработчиками WC См [Creating custom translations](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/#section-5), [Translate or replace default text](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/#section-10)

Comment: Ну это же ерунда.....Зачем какой-то костыль делать?

Comment: @Krya какая "ерунда"? Это самый правильный способ. Рекомендуемый кстати, WC. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/#section-5. А вот твой просто ломает текстовые строки.

Comment: Ваш совет выглядит как костыль. Извините :)

Comment: @Krya на самом деле костыль у тебя - ты ввел НОВЫЕ строки, которые НАДО **добавить** в лангпак  и перевести. Почитай что ли маны по переводу ВП.

Comment: Ну я думаю у человека хватит навыков для маленького проекта забить строки хардкодом на нужном языке)

Comment: @Krya ты не отличаешь создание кастомного типа контента от **перевода** строк? Твой ответ по сути даже не ответ на вопрос ТС. И я вообще не уверен. что он не вызовет конфликтов с [родной функцией](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-post-types.php). Откуда вы такое берете, интересно?